# Android web browser geo location problems on wifi - it's way off

Tags: android, browser, mobile, gps

I have this website that's designed for android phones. It gets the location of the user through the web browser... sometimes.

When I have wifi off, it switches out of lazy mode and get's an actual GPS location which is bang on the money.

When I have wifi on (and only in my office, other wifi works) it goes lazy and using the wifi to get the location. But it's saying I'm in Monaco... But I'm really in Australia.

What's up with that?

It only happens when wifi is on. And only at my office.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wifi location is based on [IP Geolocating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996106/how-does-ip-geolocating-work) which can be affected by many things.

Several company intranets I've used have reported locations waaaaaay off. In one case I think this is due to the use of a web proxy, because the location reported is the city the company headquarters is located in (and where the web proxy's running from), not the location I work at.  At another company, the location reported is in another country halfway around the world.  I'm not sure exactly what's causing this - maybe the address of my computer within the intranet maps to the internet facing IP address of a computer in another country?  Maybe there's some kind of network security software that can mis-report this? Maybe the address used to belong to a computer there, but then this company bought it?

Comment: Thanks, Nate. I was thinking it would be the MAC address rather than IP address. And I don't think we have a proxy... weird, eh?