# Why are IP Addresses so different when searched for?

Tags: ip, ip-address

I am trying to geo-locate 500 or so IP Addresses. Several online services say that for, for example, 50 addresses, 50% are in California and the other 50% in Colorado.

How do you accurately geolocate an IP address and why are some of them so off?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this Question is what you're looking for:
[How does IP geolocating work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996106/how-does-ip-geolocating-work)

The Reason why some Addresses are concentrated on single points, could be that if for a specific IP Address no entry exists, they match it to a predefined point, for example the country or town the ISP belongs to.

There is no way to get real accurate information (as mentioned in the link).