# How can Google Maps know my location so accurately

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation, location, tracking

I know that maybe they know the country where I live in, even the city, but I got a little bit shocked when I allowed my Google Chrome to get my location.

It literally showed the exact place I am right now. The exact spot, with 5 meters accuracy. How do they do that? I don't have a GPS on my PC or anything like that. Did they do that by only using my IP? So anyone who grabs my IP (say from Skype) can come and knock my door?

Comment: It may use WiFi or IP Geo Location refer [Geolocation sources](http://html5doctor.com/finding-your-position-with-geolocation/)

Comment: WiFi is most likely, to my knowledge IP Geo Location is not very precise yet, best approaches are getting close (few 10s of meters) but are quite an affort to do. I suppose google is using your search profile as well.

Comment: Related questions: [How does Google calculate my location on a desktop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668304/how-does-google-calculate-my-location-on-a-desktop), [How does IP geolocating work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996106/how-does-ip-geolocating-work), [How does HTML5 Geolocation Work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213410/how-does-html5-geolocation-work)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have GPS your location is determind by  IP Geolocation tool helps you find the approximate geographic location of an IP address along with some other useful information including ISP, TimeZone, Area Code, State etc. some company have delevoped tools for gather information about single device network ip position connect by wifi and they are  using this info for define  the position of any single WIFI device connected to the NET

Answer (score 0):

Your navigator sends data to Google about the visible WiFi nodes and Google uses this information to find your current position.

The navigator shares info like the MAC address, the SSID and the signal strength of the visible access points and the service (Google Maps) uses this info to triangulate your position.

Notice that all this depends on the concrete implementation of the HTML 5 Geolocation on each device and navigator.

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers nowadays support [HTML5 geolocation](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp) to locate a device's position (check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation) for browser's compatibility)

Chrome uses Google Location Services to estimate your position, and Google Location Services in turn [use your wifi client and cell towers information](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro).

> The Google Maps Geolocation API returns a location and accuracy radius
>   based on information about cell towers and WiFi nodes that the mobile
>   client can detect.

Same for Firefox (from [here](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/geolocation/)):

> If you consent, Firefox gathers information about nearby wireless
>   access points and your computer’s IP address. Then Firefox sends this
>   information to the default geolocation service provider, Google
>   Location Services, to get an estimate of your location. That location
>   estimate is then shared with the requesting website.

If no Wifi information is available, Google Location Services falls back to IP geolocation (i.e. identifying location from your IP address alone). Google does not disclose though which database(s) it's using for IP geolocation.